# Why values in 'main' are not changed using pointers?

Tags: c

I have some problems when I use pointers. In this program I want to input a text with `ElaboraTesto` and after with `Sdoppia` to put tokens into two different arrays:

- `StructTesto Pari[]` if their length is even.
- `StructTesto Dispari[]` if their length is odd.

Look like it works.

After I use `ordinaPari` that have to sort tokens according to their length, but when I try to print the array that contains odd tokens, with `stampaStruttura`, there is no output as well I input odd words.

I try to debug program (see code below) and I saw that `vara` and `varb` are always 0.

What am I missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DIMMAX 100

typedef char Stringa[DIMMAX];
typedef Stringa TESTO[DIMMAX];
typedef struct{

    Stringa parola;
    int lunghezza;

} StructTesto;

int ElaboraTesto(TESTO, int);
void Sdoppia(TESTO, int, StructTesto[], int* , StructTesto[], int*);
void stampaStruttura(StructTesto[], int);
void ordinaPari(StructTesto[], int);

void Sdoppia(TESTO t, int l, StructTesto Pari[], int* lp, StructTesto       Dispari[DIMMAX], int* ld){

int i;
StructTesto p;
int rest;
int j=0;
int k=0;
ld = &j;
lp = &k;

for(i=0; i<l; i++){

        strcpy(p.parola, t[i]);
        p.lunghezza = strlen(p.parola);
        rest = p.lunghezza % 2;

        if (rest != 0){

                strcpy(Dispari[j].parola ,p.parola);
                Dispari[j].lunghezza = p.lunghezza;
                j++;

        } else {

                strcpy(Pari[k].parola , p.parola);
                Pari[k].lunghezza = p.lunghezza;
                k++;

        }

}

    *ld = j;    
    *lp =k;

} 

void stampaStruttura(StructTesto array[], int n){

int i;

for(i=0; i<n; i++){

   printf("Parola: %s\n", array[i].parola);
   printf("Lunghezza: %d\n", array[i].lunghezza);
}
}

int ElaboraTesto(TESTO t, int n){

    char *tokenPtr; 
    Stringa testo;
    int i;

    printf("Inserire il testo da elaborare: (MAX %d parole)\n", DIMMAX);
    gets(testo);
    printf("Il testo che verra' tokenizzato e' il seguente:\n%s\n", testo);
    printf("I token sono:\n");

    tokenPtr = strtok(testo, " ");

    while(tokenPtr != NULL){

        printf("%s\n", tokenPtr);
        strcpy(t[i], tokenPtr);
        tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;

    }
    printf("Il testo e' composto da %d parole.\n", i);
    return i;

}

void ordinaPari(StructTesto P[], int n){

int i;
StructTesto temp;

   for(i=0; i<n; i++){

        if(P[i].lunghezza < P[i+1].lunghezza){
                temp = P[i];
                P[i] = P[i+1];
                P[i+1] = temp;
       }
  }
  }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    TESTO testo;
    int n;
    int dim;
    int vara = 0;
    int varb = 0;
    StructTesto p[DIMMAX];
    StructTesto d[DIMMAX];

    n = ElaboraTesto(testo, DIMMAX);
    Sdoppia(testo, n, p,&vara,d,&varb);
    stampaStruttura(p, n);
    ordinaPari(p,vara);
    stampaStruttura(p, vara);

    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Sdoppia` function you have these four lines:

```
int j=0;
int k=0;
ld = &j;
lp = &k;
```

The problem with this is that the pointers to the variables in the `main` function you pass in will be overwritten with the pointers to the local variables `j` and `k`.

So when you later do

```
*ld = j;    
*lp =k;
```

you are actually assigning `j` to itself and `k` to itself (i.e. you are simply doing `j = j` and `k = k`).

The solution is to not do the initial reassignments to `ld` and `lp`.